# How do I highlight changes with conditional formatting from a previous row entry in the spreadsheet?

Tags: excel

I am attempting to build a conditional formatting rule where the current row highlights the changes from a previous row entry in the spreadsheet (there could be multiple revisions over time).

After doing some research, I found the following formula that returns the previous row that has the same DASID # (therefore having an edit). DASID is a structured reference to the Event ID in Column A of the spreadsheet.

This works and returns the previous ROW # with the same DAS ID:

> {=LARGE( IF(DASID = A1389, ROW(DASID) - MIN(ROW(DASID)) + 1), 2)}

However, because I am making this a conditional format rule, the cell location needs to be calculated dynamically.

So replacing:

> DASID = A1389

With:

> DASID = (ADDRESS( ROW(), 1)) which evaluates to $A$1389
> {=LARGE( IF( DASID = (ADDRESS( ROW(),1)), ROW(DASID) - MIN(ROW(DASID))+1),2)}

However, the replacement formula generates a #NUM! error in Excel. I've also tried encapsulating with Indirect() with no luck.

> INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),1))

Once this is working, I would evaluate the different columns to identify changes and apply conditional formatting. Looking at either a fix for my formula or use a better method for highlighting changes from the last previous entry with the same ID value.

**EDIT:** Excel Snap where Event Date has changed between rows

[image: Excel Snap where Event Date has changed between rows]

CSV Data Set (Row # is created by Excel, but in data set to show that entries aren't "near" each other")

Row#,DailyActivitySheetID, Created, Modified, EventDate, Status
5,2982,11/24/2018,11/25/2018,4/6/2019,Awaiting
1286,2982,11/24/2018,2/21/2019,5/2/2019,Awaiting

| Row# | DailyActivitySheetID | Created | Modified | EventDate | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 2982 | 11/24/2018 | 11/25/2018 | 4/6/2019 | Awaiting |
| 1286 | 2982 | 11/24/2018 | 2/21/2019 | 5/2/2019 | Awaiting |

Comment: Could there be more than two DSID's? Would the fourth matching DSID have to lookup the third DSID or the first or the largest of the first, second and third?

Comment: btw, some minimal data the didn't have to be retyped from an image would help.

Comment: When you state 'DASID is a structured reference' do you mean 'DASID is a dynamic defined name'? (Formulas, Defined Names, Name Manager)

Comment: Added an image where the DASID numbers are the same. In this example there is only one prior edit, but there could be more. In this instance, I would want to find the previous row to the current and highlight that the Event Date has changed between rows.

Comment: There seem to be an ESL problem. How can I explain 'minimal data the **didn't have to be retyped from an image**' properly?

Comment: An array formula won't work in conditional formatting. Is a helper column a possibility?

Comment: An array formula does work in conditional formatting, ExcelFun has a video on it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KICLsm1OO7o. There's a few other website references as well for it, and you don't have to do ctrl+shift+enter with it. That said, I am interested in what you think is possible with a helper column?

Comment: My thought was to add a helper column to get the previous row # off to the side. Then your conditional formatting would be a simple INDEX using that row #

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there are a few steps to this.

First of all, you might want to create a dynamic range - a named range would make your final formula syntax easier - to define the target area of previous DAS Ids. There are lots of web sites that explain how to do this (using `OFFSET()` or `INDEX()`, and one would be this one: https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/dynamic-named-range.html.

So, assuming your data starts on A2 and there are no blank rows, you could add a named range called, say, `DASIDs` with this formula in its 'Refers To' window:

> =OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A)-1,1)

Note the `-1` is to exclude the bottom-most cell into which you are entering data.

Next, add a second named range that references the last row of DASIDs (for this example, I've called it `LastDASID`) with the formula:

> =OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A)-1,0,1,1)

Again, the `-1`prevents the formula offsetting beyond your data.

To read the last item in a list, there's a well-known formula that uses `SUMPRODUCT()` (here's an explanation http://www.exceluser.com/formulas/last-item-in-list.htm).

So you could add a third named range, called `MatchedDASIDRow`, with the formula:

> =SUMPRODUCT(MAX(ROW(DASIDs)*(LastDASID=DASIDs)))

So the final step is to add a conditional formatting rule in cell A2 whose rule type is `Use a formula to determine which cells to format` and select whatever formatting you desire. The rule description is basically just an amalgamation of the first three steps:

> =MatchedDASIDRow=ROW(A2)

Simply drag that conditional formatting across all rows and columns of your data area, and you should be good to go.

**Update from comment**

I think you might be better going for a VBA solution as your comments are suggestive of a pretty complex analysis requirement. However, it is possible to do this with formulas. The trick will be in finding where the prior data ends and the new data starts. Provided that your data is entered in date modified order, you could distinguish the ranges by the date modified column.

First get the dynamic range of the modified column. I've used a named range called `AllModifiedRange` and used the formula:

> =OFFSET(Sheet1!$C$1,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$C:$C),1)

Next define a formula which identifies the last row of data whose date modified is prior to today. I've called this named range `PriorModifiedsLastRow` with formula:

> =SUMPRODUCT(MAX(ROW(AllModifiedRange)*(TODAY()<>AllModifiedRange)))

This enables you to define the range of DASIDs prior to today. Named range called `PriorDASIDs` with formula:

> =OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,0,0,PriorModifiedsLastRow,1)

Now you just need to a formula, as before, to check whether the row matches the last row. Another named range called `IsPriorLastRow` with formula:

> =ROW(Sheet1!$A2)=SUMPRODUCT(MAX(ROW(PriorDASIDs)*(Sheet1!$A2=PriorDASIDs)))

However, this will highlight any of the last DASIDs. You will need a second test to determine whether the DASID exists within today's modified range.

So first define that range. I've used another named range, `TodaysModifiedRange` with the formula:

> =OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,PriorModifiedsLastRow,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A)-PriorModifiedsLastRow,1)

And then run the test. Named range called `IsInTodaysModifieds` with formula:

> =NOT(ISNA(MATCH(Sheet1!$A2,TodaysModifiedRange,0)))

So your conditional formatting formula just sees whether both tests resolve to true:

> =AND(IsPriorLastRow,IsInTodaysModifieds)

As I say, this does depend on the modified range being sorted by date and, if you enter the same DASID twice on the same day, the algorithm will fail. Personally I'd go to VBA, but if you wish to remain with Excel formulas and want greater degrees of complexity then you'll need to think through your steps and develop formulas in a structured manner.

Comment: Thanks Ambie, I followed your steps but it is not producing results. I just want to be clear, and apologies if I wasn't in original post, that It's not just the last row in the list that I am looking for. We typically have around ~20 entries added a day to the sheet, I want to be able to find the previous preexisting DASID in the sheet (if it exists and excluding the current) and highlight the changes from that previous entry. Here's a 
[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vgru3iznbobd0yo/DAS%20and%20Dates.xlsx?dl=0) to the scrubbed spreadsheet. DASID 2982 is one example.

Comment: Thanks @Ambie. I have it partially working based on the update you posted. I have to step through it a bit closer but I am stuck using formulas as the sheet is accessed via the Excel web interface by the agents in the company.

Comment: Understood. What you're trying to do is relatively complex, and does require a reasonably high level of understanding of the formulas. If you don't have so much exposure to these, it might be more efficient for your company to find a local Excel contractor to write this functionality for you. Otherwise keep playing with the formulas and keep each step simple.